# Run a shutdown script

Tags: scripts, shutdown

I'm using Ubuntu 16.0.4
I want to run a script at shutdown
I've created a file `etc/init.d/rabbitstop` as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp -b /home/admin1/hello /home/admin1/pritesh/hi
exit 0
```

And I ran

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc6.d/rabbitstop
```

also ran this command:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/rabbitstop /etc/rc0.d/K01rabbitstop
```

then shutdown PC and started again, but I'm not getting the file named `hi` at this location:

```
/home/admin1/pritesh/
```

kindly suggest a solution to me

Answer (score 3):

Make sure this directory exist : /home/admin1/pritesh
you are using ubuntu 16.04 with systemd so create a systemd unit file in `/etc/systemd/service/myunit.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=my shutdown script
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/path/to/rabbitstop

[Install]
WantedBy=halt.target reboot.target shutdown.target
```

then run

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable myunit
```

shutdown , halt or reboot to see the result .