# Gnome NVIDIA Boot Hang

Tags: boot, nvidia, gnome, intel

I have found a somewhat odd pattern and was hoping someone could explain it. I am running Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 from an external HDD on a Dell XPS 15 9560. It has both a NVIDIA GTX 1050 and Intel graphics. I have the current NVIDIA 381.22 driver for the NVIDIA card. When I am doing simple tasks, such as cruising the internet or whatever it may be, I like to switch to the Intel graphics for better power consumption. I do this either through the NVIDIA Driver by going into the prime profiles and selecting Intel, or through the terminal by:

### `sudo prime-select intel`

Both yield the same result.

The issue occurs when I either turn off or reboot while still in the Intel prime configuration. When I select to boot into Ubuntu from grub, the boot always hangs. Instead, I need to boot into recovery mode and re-enable the Nvidia card.

The problem seems to be revolving around the Intel graphics. What is the best remedy for this situation, other than remembering to switch back to the NVIDIA before shutting down? Also, it should be noted that under the additional drivers tab of the software & updates window, the driver for the Intel unit is listed as "using processor micorcoce firmware for intel CPUs from intel-microcode"

Comment: i have no experience in your issue, but I'd setup a script to detect used graphics & if intel it switches to nvidia which is run every shutdown.  a quick search found askubuntu clues on how to do shutdown-script; detection of running card I have no idea though (thus didn't look)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/848518/run-a-shutdown-script

Comment: @ guiverc do you think it may be something wrong with the Intel graphics driver? Ive been having a hard time finding any sort of documentation on this issue

Comment: i have no idea, but doubt it.  what i was suggesting was a simple script that detects which card is running (i have no idea how to do this; I assume lsmod|grep) and if it's the intel - it unloads intel & loads nvidia ... this script being every time you shutdown .... my comment was to automate your memory (script instead of you having to remember)

Comment: I've been researching this issue all day and it seems to be a fairly common issue for many people with Nvidia and Intel graphics. Everything from boot hanging, dramatic screen tearing, and constant fan noise. I'll continue doing some research, but I appreciate the help

Comment: The "using processor micorcoce firmware for intel CPUs from intel-microcode" has nothing to do with the video problem. It's updating the microcode in the processors at boot time. It's OK.

Comment: @heynnema is there a proprietary Intel graphics driver that I am missing then? Because clearly, something is missing.

Comment: No, it's probably using the built-in Intel driver. But since the Intel is probably a shared memory device, you could run a memory test just to eliminate that. Go to http://memtest86.org and download the free memory diagnostic and run at least one full pass. Do I read that your fans are constantly on? Do you know what temps you're running inside?