# Run Shutdown Script Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, shutdown, autostart

I have several services that need to be manually saved and shutdown before the server does a reboot or shutdown. I enter them manually by using a script. I was trying to figure out if I can do it automatically before the system goes down.

[Run a shutdown script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/848518/run-a-shutdown-script)

[Execute a script upon logout/reboot/shutdown in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293312/execute-a-script-upon-logout-reboot-shutdown-in-ubuntu)

https://www.tecmint.com/auto-execute-linux-scripts-during-reboot-or-startup/

The links above I tried and it hasn't succeeded. I was able to run the startup script via rc.local but the shutdown script doesn't run for some reason.

Here is my shutdown script if it was written as a systemd

/etc/systemd/system/shutdownDB.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Runs the Database Shutdown Proceedures.
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/scripts/shutdownDB

[Install]
WantedBy=halt.target reboot.target shutdown.target
```

I have placed the same file in both the rc0.d and the rc6.d using S99shutdownDB or K99shutdownDB. Inside the file is bash /scripts/shutdownDB.sh and then exit 0.

I think I am missing something else or I am not properly doing this correctly. Any help would be appreciative.

**Update 12-19-2017**

I created shutdown and restart scripts in my /scripts folder. Inside will run the commands needed and then either perform a restart or a shutdown depending on what is used. It's better to run one script rather than three. This is a band-aid solution though. I really would like to know how to get this to work properly.

Comment: Have you enabled the systemd service after you created the .service file?

Comment: I ran systemctl daemon-reload and systemctl enable shutdownDB commands after saving the service file. It created the symlinks in the want files.

Comment: Try this instead: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41756/70524

Comment: Thank you for the link. I tried all the variations listed and it's still not executing. I am trying to see if I can find a log file to shed some light on this.

Comment: `journalctl -u shutdownDB.service` might help in that

Comment: Ran the command and says no entries. Could that mean it's not running the command at all?